# Align one polygon boundary to another boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, alignment

As visualized in the picture as an example, two polygons should be aligned to each other. The boundaries of the green polygon should not be changed. The blue polygon may therefore only be adapted to the boundary of the green polygon.
The aim is to eliminate the gaps and overlaps.

I already tried [Align](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-aligning-features.htm) under ArcMap. Unfortunately, not all overlaps and gaps are removed, because the adjustment is probably made on the basis of the vertices.
The manual search for errors via topology tools would be too time-consuming, since there are many boundary problems.

[image: Gaps and overlapping areas]

Comment: Erase green by blue. Union both. Convert to polylines and back to polygons. Remove ones inside blue. Split remaining in 2 group s, large and small using select by location. Spatial join smalls to large. Merge, dissolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Reshape Feature Tool is a little time consuming, but may provide a solution. Delete all the vertices within the incorrect feature class that are near the correct boundary. Using the Erase tool or holding the Shift key while selecting vertices may assist in deleting abundant vertices.

[image]

Then click the Reshape Feature tool in the Editor toolbar. [image]

Then use the Trace tool [image]in combination with the Straight Segment tool [image] to create new vertices along the correct boundary. As shown below, the traced vertices replace the deleted vertices.

[image]

Then Finish Sketch and it should appear similar to below.

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Instead of deleting vertices manually, I used "erase" to delete everything overlapping.

Comment: Great! I will edit my answer to mention the Erase tool.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS has a tool called [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) which rehapes input polygon boundaries to be coincident with target polygon boundaries.  This tool is available at all ArcGIS License Levels.

Comment: This tool modifies both input data. One polygon should not modified at all.

Answer (score 0):

@reevesii's answer is great.
Another option, one that I use a lot is to use the "Draw Polygon" Tool in the Editor Toolbar to modify the Polygon you want to Fit to the boundary.

My work flow is as follows:

We have 2 polygons,Poly1 (Blue) and Poly2 (Purple). Poly1 needs to follow the boundary of Poly2. But Poly1 has too many vertices to manually edit.
[image]

Start an edit session and Select "Poly1" from the editing Templates. Using the "Construction Tools" select "Polygon" and digitise a rough polygon encompassing both Poly1 and Poly2. See below:

[image]

See how Poly1 now covers Poly2 completely? Poly1 is now two separate Polygons. We need to make them 1. Unselect all features, and then Select the two features within Poly1. If you are unsure that you have been able to select both features because your geometry is too complex, select them from the attribute table.

Once you have selected the features, head to the "Editor Toolbar", Select "Editor" and then the "Merge" tool.

[image]

It will then ask you which feature you want to combine **into**. In other words which attributes you want to preserve. Whichever one you click will flash on screen. So if you want to preserve the original polygon, select that one in this list.

Once you have merged the two polygons, Poly1 will be big and will cover the whole of Poly2. You now need to cut the boundary of Poly2 from Poly1. To do this simply select Poly2 on screen and again go to "Editor Toolbar" and select "Clip". If it is greyed out, make sure you have nothing else selected 1st. Also just to be safe, make sure all other layers are turned off. You want to discard all areas that overlap. See below.

[image]

Your final output will be Poly1 edited to match the outline of Poly2. This can be done with features in the same shapefile or two separate shapefiles.

[image]